# What does "good" mean in this context?

Tags: meaning-in-context

This is a passage taken from an article:

> My last job was in an air-conditioned office in a business park in Woburn, Mass., as a draftsman designing laboratories. It was like being a kitchen designer but even more boring. Every day I went into work I contemplated suicide. Was this to be the rest of my life? I finally got fired, the combination of poor job performance, a ruined economy and **good** old-fashioned New England insularity.

What does *good* mean in the sentence I bolded above?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Good old-fashioned* is a common collocation (as is *good old* almost-anything) signifying approval of old-fashioned ways of doing things.

In this case, obviously, the phrase is used ironically: the author intends us to understand that his New England employers regarded their insularity as admirable adherence to local values, but the author himself regards it quite differently.

Comment: I'm guessing the *old* in *good old-fashioned* is omitted, otherwise it would be *good old old-fashioned*?

Comment: @theo it's already there, before the hyphen :) ... But *good old* is usually reduced in speech to "good ol'" /'gʊdoʊl/, so you'll hear *good ol' ol'-fashun* a lot.

Comment: Good old Stoney; always coming up with the goods.

Comment: @BobRodes Goody goody for me.